# Java 8 - chaining constructor call and setter in stream.map()

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a class

```
class Foo{
    String name;
    // setter, getter
}
```

which just has a default constructor.

Then, I am trying to create a List of `Foo` from some string:

```
Arrays.stream(fooString.split(","))
            .map(name -> {
                Foo x = new Foo();
                x.setName(name);
                return x;

            }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Since there is no constructor which takes a name, I can't simply use a method reference. Of course, I could extract those three lines, with the constructor call and the setter, into a method but is there any better or concise way to do that? (without changing `Foo`, which is a generated file)

Comment: if only there was zip in streams...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If this happens repeatedly, you may create a generic utility method handling the problem of constructing an object given one property value:

```
public static <T,V> Function<V,T> create(
    Supplier<? extends T> constructor, BiConsumer<? super T, ? super V> setter) {
    return v -> {
        T t=constructor.get();
        setter.accept(t, v);
        return t;
    };
}
```

Then you may use it like:

```
List<Foo> l = Arrays.stream(fooString.split(","))
    .map(create(Foo::new, Foo::setName)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note how this isn’t specific to `Foo` nor its `setName` method:

```
List<List<String>> l = Arrays.stream(fooString.split(","))
    .map(create(ArrayList<String>::new, List::add)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

By the way, if `fooString` gets very large and/or may contain lots of elements (after splitting), it might be more efficient to use `Pattern.compile(",").splitAsStream(fooString)` instead of `Arrays.stream(fooString.split(","))`.

Comment: dear holger would you provide me with a link to a good tutorial to learn using this skill, is  this a pattern, do this way of doing have a name ??

Answer (score 11):

No, there is no better way.

The only alternative is, like you said in your question, to create a factory for `Foo` objects:

```
public class FooFactory {
    public static Foo fromName(String name) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setName(name);
        return foo;
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Arrays.stream(fooString.split(",")).map(FooFactory::fromName).collect(toList());
```

If there are a lot of names to split, you can use `Pattern.compile(",").splitAsStream(fooString)` (and store the compiled pattern in a constant to avoid recreation) instead of `Arrays.stream(fooString.split(","))`.

Answer (score 8):

In this case you don't have too many alternatives unless you add a constructor taking the name as parameter, or you create a [static factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) that create your instance .

Answer (score 5):

`.map(n -> new Foo() {{ name = n; }} )`

This uses an initialization block to set an instance-variable.

There is however a caveat: The returned objects will not actually be of type `Foo` but of new, anonymous classes which extend `Foo`. When you follow the Liskov substitution principle this should not be a problem, but there are a few situations where it might be a concern.

Comment: ...or: .map(n -> new Foo() {{ setName(n); }} )

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative that no one mentioned yet would be to subclass `Foo` class, however this may have some disadvantages - it's difficult to say whether it would be appropriate solution to your problem, as I don't know the context.

```
public class Bar extends Foo {

    public Bar(String name) {
        super.setName(name);
    }

}
```